# Why there is nothing to print when I use Bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm new to Bootstrap, and I just started to build some navbar with it! the code is like this

```
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">ASiDesigner</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">

      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home </a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contacts</a>
          <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
              <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-primary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
      </ul>
    </div>
    </nav>
```

But when I hit Ctrl+P in chrome or Firefox to print, they show nothing in print preview, also when I print it to PDF, the page is blank also, I'm using Bootstrap 4.3.1

I want to design a simple page and print it into the PDF! That's all, but so far I just got a blank page. What's wrong or what should I do to complete the task?

The final Goal is a PDF that has all the navbar and links and it should work.

Comment: you have to change the print styles from bootstrap (or don't include them). default styling for bootstrap is to not print the navigation

Comment: Thanks, I just commented this section in Bootstarp    
@media print {
  
  }  and still no lock! I just empty it!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know why exactly some libraries and functions don't seem as it should be when you want to print the HTML file .I needed to do in the past what you're trying to do and I found this website https://pdfcrowd.com .I saved your code in my notepad and uploaded this website to see how it seems and as PDF that seems below perfect as you wish.I hope it helps
[image]